# Thymeleaf conditional JavaScript function call

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm developing a ***Spring Boot*** web application with ***Thymeleaf*** as the template engine.

I want to call a JavaScript function as soon as the page loads, if a specific attribute is present in the Model.

I did some research and I found a way to call a function but with clicking on a span etc., which doesn't do the job for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You basically want to call a `Javascript` method depending on a `Thymleaf` variable as soon as the page loads.

Try this

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var flag = [[${flag}]]; //Your Thymleaf variable
    window.onload = function() {
        if(!flag)
            return; // Exit/Return if the variable is false
        spreadLove(); // Call your favourite method if the variable is true
    };

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, it works just as i wanted to. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer bro